# javascript output line break

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've modified a very simple calculation form I found on the Web.  The result, which is working as expected here: http://kosherhealthfitness.com/khf/fitness-activities/injury-prevention/bike-pain.html, looks like this:

```
 <!--Calculator Form-->
     <form id="symptomChecker" oninput="updateSource()">
     <select class="symptoms" id="painType" name="painType" onchange="updateSource()">
       <option value="0">Select</option>
       <option value="1">Foot/Ankle</option>
       <option value="2">Knee</option>
       <option value="3">Hip</option>
       <option value="4">Back</option>
       <option value="5">Shoulder</option>
       <option value="6">Hand</option>
     </select> 
     <output class="symptoms" id="painSource" name="painSource">Possible Sources: </output>
     </form> 
     <!--End Calculator Form-->
```

With the following script:

```
<script>
    function updateSource() { 
            //get form
        var form = document.getElementById("symptomChecker");
            //get output
        var out = form.elements["painSource"];
        var painArea = parseInt(form.elements["painType"].value);
            //set output depending on painArea
        switch(painArea)
        {
            //Select
            case 0:
            out.value = "Ouch";
            break;
            //Foot
            case 1: out.value = "Ouch Foot";
            break;
            //Knee
            case 2: out.value = "Ouch Knee";
            break;
            //Hip
            case 3: out.value = "Ouch Hip";
            break;
            //Back
            case 4: out.value = "Ouch Knee"
            break;
            //Shoulder
            case 5: out.value = "Ouch Shoulder"
            break;
            //Hand
            case 6: out.value = "Ouch Hand"
            break;

            default:
            break;
        }
    }

    </script>
```

What I'm trying to do is add some html, and possibly css, to the out.value.  For example, I need line breaks so that I can get lists with some simple formatting. I've tried 
 and \n, but those are just newbie guesses.

Without redoing the entire form, is there a simple way to insert html and css for the out.value?

Comment: Just use something else than output. Make a simple div and modify its content with getElementById("output").innHTML="cool <br>";

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Which code am I modifying with your example?

Answer (score 0):

I think as `output` is effectively a form-input tag, its `.value` property can only take text. It's equivalent to setting `.innerText` on any regular element. So when you add a `<br />` tag or something to the value, it just becomes regular text.

I don't know what accessibility advantages using `output.value` will give you, but you could alternatively use a `div` or `span` and `.innerHTML` to inject HTML tags as well as text.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <div class="symptoms" id="painSource" name="painSource">Possible Sources: </div>

<script>
function updateSource() {
var form = document.getElementById("symptomChecker");
var out = document.getElementById("output");
var painArea = parseInt(form.elements["painType"].value);   
 switch(painArea) { 
 case 0: 
    out.innerHTML = "Ouch";
  break;
 case 1: 
    out.innerHTML = "Ouch Foot"; 
 break; 
 default: 
 break; } } 
 </script>
```

Comment: My bad. Forgot to change out.value to out.innerHTML.  Trying now.

Comment: Did you changed output to div and the var out?

Comment: Changed output to div per your code.  I don't see what you mean by "and the var out?" Sorry for my slowness tonight.  And my FTP is choking on top of everything else.

Comment: var out = document.getElementById("output");

Comment: OK.  It think I  have it working almost (damn FTP is still choking).  There was a mismatch between the div and the script.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try This. This will work for you.

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/44y29dk7/)

HTML:

```
<select class="symptoms" id="painType" name="painType1" >
   <option value="0">Select</option>
   <option value="1">Foot/Ankle</option>
   <option value="2">Knee</option>
   <option value="3">Hip</option>
   <option value="4">Back</option>
   <option value="5">Shoulder</option>
   <option value="6">Hand</option>
 </select> 
 <output class="symptoms" id="painSource" name="painSource">Possible Sources: </output>
```

Script:

```
$("#painType").change(function () {
    var str = "";
 str =   $( "#painType option:selected" ).text();
    $("#painSource").html("Ouch " +str );
  })
```

Comment: It looks like you kept <output></output> instead of <div>.  But where are suggesting I put the script code: $("#painType...  And what does that do?

Comment: Have you tried this.? or directly you have down vote.? I have updated this. try added link.

Comment: I tried it at jsfiddle.  But I don't see how it solves my problem.  Ouch Back etc. were only place holders for testing the code.  I have lists I want to add instead.

Comment: And I don't understand your comment about down vote.